# Cartopy Cimgt not retrieving tiles within PySpark notebook

Tags: cartopy

Cartopy version 0.18.0.  This works in a juptyer notebook:

```
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
extent =[-94, -84, 43, 37]
request=cimgt.GoogleTiles(desired_tile_form='RGB', style='street')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent(extent)
ax.add_image(request, 6)
plt.show()
```

However, when I attempt to do the exact same thing in a pyspark notebook with Cartopy 0.18.0 added as a package library, I get this error:

```
ValueError: A non-empty list of tiles should be provided to merge.
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my pyspark environment was not set up correctly.  Issue is resolved.